# Android in-app-purchase validation on backend

Tags: c#, android, google-api

I'm using validation of user's in app purchase with google API:
Purchases.products: get
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get

In C# on the backend I create HttpWebRequest with this url:

```
var url = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{0}/purchases/products/{1}/tokens/{2}", packageName, androidProductId, token);
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
```

The parameters packageName, productId and token, were set correctly.
After I send the request, google answers me with the next JSON object:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

So, the problem is about authorization my backend server. How could this be fixed?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/androidpublisher/v2

Answer (score -1):

I use IAP for authorization on backend server. Please read this [article](https://habrahabr.ru/post/313416/)(russian language).